# Automatically running a script on a file as it is created via SAMBA

Tags: files, scripting, samba

I have a Linux machine acting as a local SAMBA file server. Most of the clients are Windows. The server is only accessible from within my intranet, and it only serves photos (jpg, gif, png, etc).

What I want is to rename all files as they are created on the share, so that the filenames reflect the creation time of each file. I am not married to a specific solution. I could write a Python script, or I might use `rename` as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/511793/1084192). Or something else :)

I know I could do this as a post-processing step, but I want to make it more user-proof. Can it be automated?

Addition info:

Each user has a different account and SAMBA password, and are part of the 'repository' group. This group has r/w access to the SAMBA share. All files/directories created via SAMBA are user:repository and group:repository. Here is the relevant part of smb.conf:

```
[photos]
path = /mnt/repository/photos/
valid users = @repository
force group = repository
inherit owner = yes
create mask = 0660
force create mode = 0660
directory mask = 0770
force directory mode = 0770
writeable = yes
public = no
mangled names = illegal
hosts deny = ALL
hosts allow = 192.168.125.32/27
```

The drive is an external USB HDD. It's formatted NTFS. I have it mounted `noexec`, although I could change this if necessary.

Comment: I think you're out of luck. The Windows NTFS filesystem doesn't support `iwatch`. That is, `iwatch` needs hooks into the filesystem, which Windows NTFS does not provide. You could do this the old way by using a `cron` job that starts every minute (be sure to think about what happens if one execution takes longer that a minute). `man -a crontab`

Comment: Thanks, @waltinator, I suspect you are right. But I hope someone will come up with something clever :)